# How do I convert a querystring to a json string in dotnet core?

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-4.0

how can I convert a query string to a JSON string of keys and values? For example, I want to convert

```
"ID=123&FNAME=test&LNAME=xyz"
```

to

```
{"ID":"123","FNAME":"test","LNAME":"xys"}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using asp.net core, I suggest you could use System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer class to achieve your requirement.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("ID=123&FNAME=test&LNAME=xyz");
        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(
                            dict.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k])
                   );
```

Result:

[image]